# SearchView as WebView Url/Google Search Bar

Tags: java, android, webview, searchview

Im trying to use a SearchView as a url/google search. Ive read from the developer site on what to do but my app will not let me search no matter what. Currently Im struck trying out this method. I would like it to search google if it doesn't contain .com/ca/org etc... but the way I have it now it won't load into the webView.

Main.Java

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    assert searchManager != null;
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    Intent searchIntent = getIntent();
    String query = searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchIntent.getAction())) {

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.ca/result/?q="+query);

    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I don't know what other ways to do at this time. So I'm asking for help,
if you need to see more of the file just ask.

logCat

```
  '01-17 15:47:47.653 1583-1620/? E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.equiware.mickeyt.unite
                                              java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.equiware.mickeyt.unite is currently frozen!
                                                  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:3520)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3936)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3896)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3777)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1440)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2676)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:2183)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1861)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.resumeFocusedStackTopActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1851)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5405)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6806)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killPackageProcessesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6466)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6606)
                                                  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2059)
                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
01-17 15:47:47.767 1583-1622/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 29664
01-17 15:47:47.909 29504-29504/? E/PhoneWindow: Circular progress bar not located in current window decor
01-17 15:47:48.052 1583-2282/? E/OverlayManager: Cannot found overlays for target: com.equiware.mickeyt.unite
01-17 15:47:48.052 1583-2282/? E/OverlayManager: Cannot found overlays for target: com.equiware.mickeyt.unite
01-17 15:47:48.057 2572-2572/? E/FMFRW_LgFmService: The Service for Chip Vendor is not ready
01-17 15:47:48.067 2321-2321/? E/SystemServicesProxy: recent task thumbnail from AM is null, and descriptor is null
01-17 15:47:48.104 2945-2945/? E/LCardEmulationManager: initDefaultRoutePath() - route : 243
01-17 15:47:48.145 1583-2282/? E/OverlayManager: Cannot found overlays for target: com.equiware.mickeyt.unite
01-17 15:47:48.159 2321-2423/? E/KeyguardModel: package:  not found!
01-17 15:47:48.159 2321-2423/? E/KeyguardModel: package:  not found!
01-17 15:47:48.161 2321-2423/? E/KeyguardModel: package:  not found!
01-17 15:47:48.310 2321-2321/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find. provider info for com.lge.lgpay.lockscreen.shortcut
01-17 15:47:48.310 2321-2321/? E/com.lge.lockscreen.widget.draglayer.AbsUnlockHandler: Failed to show the LG Quick Pay shortcut : LG Pay is not exist or an exception has occured.
01-17 15:47:48.582 30170-30170/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
01-17 15:47:48.599 30174-30174/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
01-17 15:47:48.737 2885-11015/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
01-17 15:47:48.737 2885-11015/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
s01-17 15:47:48.768 4100-4696/? E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed com.equiware.mickeyt.unite
01-17 15:47:48.987 30178-30256/? E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-17 15:47:49.029 30178-30178/? E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
 01-17 15:47:49.143 29812-29812/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bp.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
  01-17 15:47:49.235 1583-2122/? E/WifiScanner: listener cannot be found
 01-17 15:47:49.552 3512-3512/? E/WidgetViewCreator: setBgColorForSmartBulletin called
 01-17 15:47:49.553 3512-3512/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lge.launcher2.smartbulletin
 01-17 15:47:50.226 2885-14359/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
01-17 15:47:50.226 2885-14359/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
01-17 15:47:51.010 3512-3512/? E/WidgetViewCreator: setBgColorForSmartBulletin called
01-17 15:47:51.010 3512-3512/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lge.launcher2.smartbulletin
01-17 15:47:51.022 3512-3512/? E/WidgetViewCreator: setBgColorForSmartBulletin called
01-17 15:47:51.023 3512-3512/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lge.launcher2.smartbulletin
 01-17 15:47:51.048 3512-3512/? E/WidgetViewCreator: setBgColorForSmartBulletin called
01-17 15:47:51.049 3512-3512/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lge.launcher2.smartbulletin
01-17 15:47:51.090 30459-30459/? E/LocationManager: [LGNSS] Disable_PrivacyLocation_Information [tOperator : RGS ] , [privacy_check : NA]
 01-17 15:47:51.102 1583-3083/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
01-17 15:47:51.102 1583-3083/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
 01-17 15:47:51.126 1583-3083/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
 01-17 15:47:51.170 30459-30459/? E/BatteryUtils:  wifiPowerPerPacket :2.7306666666666667E-4 mobilePowerPerms : 5.1441666666666666E-5 mobilePowerPerPacket 1.1705837037037035E-6
01-17 15:47:52.697 851-1023/? E/ThermalEngine: TM Id 'LCD_ON_MONITOR' Sensor 'lcd-brightness' - alarm  raised 1 at 255.0 degC
01-17 15:48:00.141 3512-3512/? E/WidgetViewCreator: setBgColorForSmartBulletin called
01-17 15:48:00.144 3512-3512/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lge.launcher2.smartbulletin
01-17 15:48:04.227 30527-30527/? E/Pref: get_inner_onoff: false
01-17 15:48:04.233 30527-30527/? E/MYPLACE_Utils: activityFinish
01-17 15:48:04.236 30527-30527/? E/MYPLACE_Receiver: onReceive com.lge.myplace.myplace_settings_search_intent
01-17 15:48:04.236 30527-30527/? E/MYPLACE_Receiver: INTENT_MYPLACE_SETTINGS_SEARCH false
01-17 15:48:04.239 30527-30527/? E/Pref: get_onoff: 0
 01-17 15:48:04.489 30515-30515/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bp.a(847): onConnectionFailed:     ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}'
```

Comment: so… what fails? the if statement?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I added the logcat

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I implement the methode from [this site](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/implementing-searchview-in-android-actionbar.html).

My ***WebViewActivity.java***

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
    if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){

        MenuBuilder menuBuilder = (MenuBuilder) menu;
        menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.clearFocus();
//Called when the user submits the query. This could be due to a key press on the keyboard or due to pressing a submit button.
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.id/search?q="+query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
//Called when the query text is changed by the user.
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

For your case, just replace your url string

> https://google.ca/result/?q=

with

> https://www.google.ca/search?q=

Then My ***webview_menu.xml***

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

The Documentation is [right here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html).